# formal expression tree

Tags: cart

Let the covariate space be divided in $J$ disjoint regions $R_j,\; j\in\{1,...,J\}$. Let $\gamma_j$ be a value assigned to region $R_j$. For a decision tree the regions denote the terminal nodes. Then, Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman (*Elements of Statistical Learning*, *second edition*) state that a tree can be formally expressed as $$T(x;\{R_j,\gamma_j\}_{j=1}^J)=\sum_{j=1}^J\gamma_j I(x\in R_j),$$

where $I(\cdot)$ is the indicator function and $x$ is the set of covariates corresponding to some observation.

I do not see why this is a formal expression for a tree. Why is there a sum? What does this equation mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informally, the sum says: "return the value $\gamma_j$ when $x$ is in the set $R_j$. Here's why:

Saying the $R_j$ are disjoint regions means that any $x$ will belong to at most one of the regions $R_j$.  That implies that at most one of the terms $I(x \in R_j)$ will equal one.  Since those terms multiply the $\gamma_j$, the sum will equal one of the gammas*.

A decision tree splits a domain into disjoint regions.  So given a decision tree, it's possible to get a set of the regions it splits the covariate space into ${R_j}$.  Some information may be lost going from a tree to regions, i.e. the order of the decisions that are made.  But that doesn't affect the function of $x$ that the tree results in.

*Assuming the $R_j$ cover the domain of $x$

Comment: Aah okay! It is clear now. Thanks.